# python multiple input multiple output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, input, multiple-input

I wrote a program that gets 4 input in a line from user and it's in a loop. My problem is that if in different iterations the user want to give less than 4 input the program accept them and save them in n first variable that are in code and the program doesn't get an error

```
while True: 
name,arg1,arg2,arg3 = input().split()
arg2 , arg3 = int(arg2),int(arg3)
if name == "define":
    x.define(arg1,arg2,arg3)
elif name == "delete":
    x.delete(arg1)
elif name == "sell":
    x.sell(arg1,arg2)
elif name == "buy":
    x.buy(arg1,arg2)
elif name == "status":
    x.status()

elif name == "financial":
    x.financial()

elif name == "exit":
    break

else:
    print("Wrong input\a")
```

so for example if the user want to call the status function he must to enter 3 useless input

Comment: You can try to validate input on every iteration.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including example code, sample input, and expected and actual results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You've described some behavior on a program we can't see. What is your question?

Comment: Do you really need to use both 3.x and 2.7? 2.7 has been EOL for years, you should not use it without a strong need.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your problem. But I modify your code:

```
While True: 
   try: 
      x = []
      x = input().split(' ')
      if x[0] == "define":
         x.define(x[1],x[2],x[3])
      #Rest of code
   except:
       print('Wrong input')
```